# Why are utf-8 emojis not getting rendered in my pandas dataframe when I read from the SQL database?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have the following line to read from a csv file:

```
coronavirus_df = pd.read_csv('Path\coronavirus_March-3-2020.csv')
```

I Have this other lines to read from MSSQL:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc 
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                  'Server=MyServer;'
                  'Database=Mydb;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
sql_tweets_df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM my table',conn)
```

In both cases, I can get the data from the data sources and create a data frame, but there is an important difference:

```
coronavirus_df['text'].loc[9] gives the result:
-> 'YEP some more text.'

sql_tweets_df['Text'].loc[9] gives this other result:
-> 'YEP ðŸ‘\x8d some more text'
```

Why is this happening?, the emoji is not rendered when I'm getting the information from the database.
In both the database and in the excel file, that record seems to be precisely the same.

I'm using python 3 and Jupyter notebooks